# Need help setting up subversion

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

We are a small company working on a source of a big company. We are actually setting up 
Subversion with Apache server to work on their code. We need to setup a secure environment so that others outside my group should not have access. I heard there are lot of authentication techniques that can be set up with apache server. Can some one help what are the most secure techniques that come up with apache server and are good with subversion.

Answer (score 1):

The [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html) goes over several methods of doing authentication.  It sounds to me like this is a matter of simply setting up the appropriate security groups, and less about what matter of authentication you use.

If you happen to have an Active Directory or LDAP server, you can use the groups there to define who has access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure that this is only available over SSL. Apache makes it pretty easy to set up svn repositories with authentication. The configuration snippit below will serve an SVN repository on svn.domain.com with HTTP authentication.

```
<Location />
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "svn.domain.com"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /srv/domain/htauth/svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /srv/domain/repositories
</Location>
```